# Multiple Between Dates from table column

Tags: sql, datetime, multiple-columns, between

There is yearly data in the source. I need to exclude the data -which is in another table and raw count is not static- from it.

Source data:

[image]

Dates to be excluded:

[image]

There can be 2 raws or 5 raws of data to be excluded, so it need to be dynamically and 2 tables can be bound by the DISPLAY_NAME column.

I am trying to do it with query, don't want to use sp. Is there any way or sp is only choise to do this.

Maybe multiple case when for each raw 1 / 0 and only get if all new case when columns are 1 but issue is don't know how many case when i will use since exclude table data raw count is not static.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `not exists`?

```
select s.*
from source s
where not exists (select 1
                  from excluded e
                  where e.display_name = s.display_name and
                        s.start_datetime >= e.start_date and
                        s.end_datetime < e.end_date
                 );
```

Note:  Your question does not explain how the `end_date` should be handled.  This assumes that the data on that date should be included in the result set.  You can tweak the logic to exclude data from that date as well.

Comment: I should exclude data that START_DATETIME not between START_DATE and END_DATE